# "user:me" does not work when searching all sites on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

When I go to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) I can see I am logged in.

I do a search for `user:me [ssh]`, so I can find all questions I have asked or answered that are tagged with `ssh`

The search page then shows all results, not just ones that pertain to me. It also now says "**log in**" as if I am not logged in. Yet if I click the logo taking me to the home page it switches back to "**John Isaacks log out**" indicating that I am logged in.

I am not sure the bug is whats keeping me from searching all sites for user:me or not. So I am tagging it as both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: I can see a bit of logic as to why it can't work in the current system. Your user id is generally going to be different for every site (including stackexchange.com itself), so if the `user:X` operator actually worked your search results would be... very unrelated. However, as a feature request this would be something interesting to add, as it would require something more complex than how the `user:me` operator probably currently works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

stackexchange.com search uses Google Custom Search instead of the Stack Exchange search. Thus, SE custom search operators are not available.

Comment: Search is hard, let's go shopping!